# Full width video with bootstrap container on top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, text

I have a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cb1er9mp/7/)

I would like to have a full width video with text on top that is in a bootstrap container.

The text on top of the video will respond like the text below the video.

```
    <div class="video-block block">
        <video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" autoplay muted loop ></video>
    </div>

    <div class="container text header-info">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container text">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The video is not loading in the fiddle and you need to clearly explain what the issue is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cb1er9mp/11/ I have updated with an image - on top of the full width image I would like text in a bootstrap container, so it will respond like the text below the image in the green container.

Answer (score 1):

I set a `min-height to top Header to 300px` (height of video in css) and set it `relative position`

I set a video block an absolute position to top 0

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0e63w4oc/)**

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container text header-info">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="video-block block">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1640/480/any">
</div>

<div class="container text text-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.block{
   position: relative;
    z-index: -1; 
}

.video-block{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;    
}

video{
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.text{
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.header-info{
    top: 0;
    min-height:300px;        
}

.text-2{
    background: green;
}
```